# Long Power BI SSAS request execution

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, powerbi, olap, olap-cube

Tell me, please, what are the limitations of the Power BI when receiving data using SQL Server Analysis Services? It usually takes a very long time to get data consisting of 100 thousand lines for example (1,5 hours). Also, a timeout occurs and the request is not executed at all. How can I optimize this?

My query that goes timeout:

```
SELECT 
{
    [Measures].[P&L ACT],
    [Measures].[P&L Budget],
    [Measures].[P&L LY]
}
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS , NON EMPTY
CrossJoin(
    {[Date].[Year].&[2017]},
    {[Date].[Month].&[2017]&[1],
    [Date].[Month].&[2017]&[2],
    [Date].[Month].&[2017]&[3],
    [Date].[Month].&[2017]&[4],
    [Date].[Month].&[2017]&[5],
    [Date].[Month].&[2017]&[6],
    [Date].[Month].&[2017]&[7],
    [Date].[Month].&[2017]&[8],
    [Date].[Month].&[2017]&[9],
    [Date].[Month].&[2017]&[10],
    [Date].[Month].&[2017]&[11],
    [Date].[Month].&[2017]&[12]},
    {[Channel].[Channel1].Children},
    {[Channel].[Channel2].Children},
    {[Product].[Brand].Children},
    {[Product].[Brand Cluster].Children},
    {[Product].[Package Type].Children},
    {[Product].[Product Type].Children},
    {[Region].[Region].Children},
    {[PL Natural].[PL Natural].[Level 0]},
    {[Budget Type].[Budget Type].&[1], 
    [Budget Type].[Budget Type].&[2], 
    [Budget Type].[Budget Type].&[3], 
    [Budget Type].[Budget Type].&[4]})
ON ROWS 
FROM [Revenue]
```

Comment: Can you post the MDX calc for your three measures? And can you test the query with one measure at a time and tell us which measure is slowest and if any measure returns substantially more rows.

Comment: SSAS MD is not optimized for this sort of "data dump" query. I would try to bypass it and query the source SQL tables if possible.

Comment: "P&L LY" measure is the slowest. LY = Actual-1Year. Unfortunately using the SQL source tables is not possible.